# resume the First activity again instead of going to second activity

Tags: android, twitter4j

i am using two activities in twitter android linked app. the first activity is LoginActivity and second is TweetslistActivity. i have used a button in loginActivity and on its click,twitter login dialog opens. when user successfully logs in,then my app should open second activity. but after user is authenticated ,my first activity resumes and i have to click login button again to go to my second activity!

```
 the logcat shows:
08-30 05:05:48.477: I/dalvikvm-heap(4205): Grow heap (frag case) to 6.686MB for 4194320-byte allocation
08-30 05:05:48.557: D/dalvikvm(4205): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 3% free 6732K/6920K, paused 76ms, total 76ms
08-30 05:05:49.288: D/gralloc_goldfish(4205): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-30 05:05:55.757: V/tweetsData--(4205): null
08-30 05:06:11.897: E/Twitter Login Error(4205): > No Token available.
```

i have also used 'android:launchMode="singleTask"' in Manifest file. but it just directs me from first activity to second without login! i am just stuck but didn't get any answer.. pls suggest some good solutions. thank you in advance.

**EDIT:**

Original code:

```
public class TwitterLoginActivity extends Activity {
    TextView tv;
    Button loginBtn;
    ImageView logo;
    private ConnectionDetector cd;
    static Twitter twitter;
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    ArrayList<String> tweets;
    String tweetsData;

    private static SharedPreferences mSharedPreferences;
    AlertDialogManager alert = new AlertDialogManager();
    RequestToken requestToken;
    AccessToken accessToken;
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.twitter_login);
            tweets = new ArrayList<String>();
            setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
                    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                                    .permitAll().build();
                    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
            }
            cd = new ConnectionDetector(getApplicationContext());
            if (!cd.isConnectingToInternet()) {
                    alert.showAlertDialog(TwitterLoginActivity.this,
                                    "Internet Connection Error",
                                    "Please connect to working Internet connection", false);
                    return;
            }

            if (CONSUMER_KEY.trim().length() == 0
                            || CONSUMER_SECRET.trim().length() == 0) {
                    // Internet Connection is not present
                    alert.showAlertDialog(TwitterLoginActivity.this, "Twitter oAuth tokens",
                                    "Please set your twitter oauth tokens first!", false);
                    return;
            }

            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome_txt);
            loginBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login_btn);
            logo = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            mSharedPreferences = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref",
                            0);

            loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                            Thread th = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                                    public void run() {
                                            loginToTwitter();
                                    }
                            });
                            th.start();

                    }
            });

            if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
                    Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
                    if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
                            uri.getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);

                            try {

                                    AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken);
                                    Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
                                    e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
                                    e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, accessToken.getTokenSecret());
                                    e.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
                                    e.commit();

                                    Log.e("Twitter OAuth Token", "> " + accessToken.getToken());

                            }
                            catch (Exception e) {
                                    Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
                            }
                    }
            }

    }

    public void loginToTwitter() {
            if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
                    ConfigurationBuilder builder = new ConfigurationBuilder();
                    builder.setOAuthConsumerKey(CONSUMER_KEY);
                    builder.setOAuthConsumerSecret(CONSUMER_SECRET);
                    Configuration configuration = builder.build();
                    TwitterFactory factory = new TwitterFactory(configuration);
                    twitter = factory.getInstance();
                    try {
                            requestToken = twitter.getOAuthRequestToken(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL);
                            this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri
                                            .parse(requestToken.getAuthenticationURL()))); }
                            });

                    }
                    catch (TwitterException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }
                    Intent intent = new Intent(TwitterLoginActivity.this, TweetsListActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("tweetsdata",tweetsData);
                    startActivity(intent);

                    finish();               }


    private boolean isTwitterLoggedInAlready() {
            return mSharedPreferences.getBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
            super.onResume();

    }

}
```

Comment: Post your code. you are using dialog or webview based authentication?

Comment: here is the code http://pastebin.com/PGYiUhd0

Comment: startActivityForResult(), then if success, start second activity, this.finish()

Comment: Please add the code to your question. It is important for other readers in the future to have the code here. Thanks.

Comment: share some code here...

Comment: the question is edited and now the code is pasted above.

Answer (score 0):

Put this code that was at the end of onCreate() to onResume() with my changes:

```
Uri uri = getIntent().getData();
if (uri != null && uri.toString().startsWith(TWITTER_CALLBACK_URL)) {
    uri.getQueryParameter(URL_TWITTER_OAUTH_VERIFIER);

    try {
        AccessToken accessToken = twitter.getOAuthAccessToken(requestToken);
        Editor e = mSharedPreferences.edit();
        e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_TOKEN, accessToken.getToken());
        e.putString(PREF_KEY_OAUTH_SECRET, accessToken.getTokenSecret());
        e.putBoolean(PREF_KEY_TWITTER_LOGIN, true);
        e.commit();

        Log.e("Twitter OAuth Token", "> " + accessToken.getToken());
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Twitter Login Error", "> " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

if (!isTwitterLoggedInAlready()) {
    // Goto TweetsListActivity
    Intent intent = new Intent(TwitterLoginActivity.this, TweetsListActivity.class);
    intent.putExtra("tweetsdata",tweetsData);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Also be aware that on your code in lines 127-128 these lines are switched:

```
     startActivity(intent);
     intent.putExtra("tweetsdata",tweetsData);
```

After start activity there is no sense to change the intent.

**EDIT:**

Also noticed this code after startActivity() for the web login, which don't make any sense:

```
TwitterLoginActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(TwitterLoginActivity.this,
                TweetsListActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("tweetsdata",tweetsData);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }
});
```

Remove this code.

Comment: it just moving the first activity to another on button click. the log in page does not work here

Comment: This should work to go to second activity after returning from web login. When you come from web login this activity is resumed, so there you need to check the login. If the web login is not working, it is not related to your original question.

Comment: i try the code by removing intent as u suggested,but for this i also have to delete else statement and put intent after catch block. it works.i have edited the code above. but still the problem relating "No token available" and resuming of first activity after login not solved. i am still at same place.